# Выборка из одной таблицы строк с разными значениями столбца

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим, есть новости по спорту и экономике. Создана таблица, в которой есть столбец cat, отвечающий за принадлежность новости к сфере спорта (cat=1) или экономике (cat=2)
На главной странице сайта хочу, чтобы в блоке СПОРТ выводились последние 2 новости из спорта, а в блоке ЭКОНОМИКА столько же (т.е. 2 последних) новостей экономики
Можно ли это реализовать одним запросом к БД?

Пробовал

```sql
SELECT
  t1.title AS r1,
  t2.title AS r2
FROM
  (SELECT cat, title FROM news WHERE cat=1 LIMIT 2) t1
  join (SELECT cat,title FROM news WHERE cat=2 LIMIT 2) t2
```

Но у меня получается в ответе массив из 4 элементов вместо 2

Пример ответа:

```php
Array (
[0] => Array ( [0] => Новость_Спорт_один [1] => Новость_Эк_один )
[1] => Array ( [0] => Новость_Спорт_два [1] => Новость_Эк_один )
[2] => Array ( [0] => Новость_Спорт_один [1] => Новость_Эк_два )
[3] => Array ( [0] => Новость_Спорт_два [1] => Новость_Эк_два )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cat, title FROM news WHERE cat=1 LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT cat,title FROM news WHERE cat=2 LIMIT 2
```